# JQuery Issues With Wordpress Theme Interface

Tags: jquery, templates, errors

I'm having a back-end script issue with a recently installed theme. I took it up with the theme developer, but they are of no help (that's another story for another time). I apologize if this is outside the scope of this site, but I'm at a loss for help.

Basically, I had a fully functional WP site running 3.4.2. I decided to add a new theme (MikMag by ThemeDutch) and it actually works fine on the front end. The problem I'm having is in the theme's UI, trying to create sliders. I have the theme installed on another site and it works fine. However, on this install it's throwing script errors when I try to use the slider interface. I have disabled all plugins with no change.

I'm comfortable with CSS, HTML, and even minor PHP, but this stuff is beyond me. Since the site is live I don't want to start messing around with anything without knowing what I'm doing!

Below is a link to a screen cap showing the errors. All of the called upon scripts appear to be exactly where they need to be when I look at the site via FTP.

Here is the working version: http://www.unitytactical.com/screen2.jpg

And the broken version: http://www.unitytactical.com/screen.jpg

As you can see a whole section is missing, and clicking the "Add Slide" link does nothing.

Hopefully this is something simple and stupid. Regardless, I truly appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to view the missing file in your browser?

Comment: Yes, it brings up the same box with just the dysfunctional "Add Slide" link.

Also maybe worth mentioning, the slide options are called into an iframe window. This seems to be working fine, it simply does not pull up the rest of the content.

I tried using the "Use Google Libraries" plugin which didn't work for the busted version, and when added to the functioning site actually caused the exact same issue. Obviously something is conflicting, but all plugins are deactivated. I'm clueless.

Comment: No, you didn’t: `http://www.unitytactical.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.core.min.js` is not on your website. Upload the complete WordPress core (again).

Comment: Close-voted as **too localized**. As this is a commercial Theme, we have no way to see the Theme code, and thus have no way to determine the nature of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

toscho...you were partly correct but helped immensely. Turns out the issue seems to lie within the theme's attempt at calling up the scripts. My WP install is in a subfolder (/wp/) and it was looking for the wp-include scripts in the root folder. All other aspects of the site work fine, so I assume this is just an error somewhere in the theme's code. I "fixed" the problem by copying the /wp-include/js folder into the root of the site and low and behold it's functioning properly now. This is definitely a band-aid fix though as I'm using duplicate script locations, but since it appears to only affect this one area of the admin panel it shouldn't cause any issues.

I've dug around the theme's relevant PHP files and can't find where the problem lies. Should I look into this further or accept my workaround as a fix? Either way, I appreciate the input as it led me in the right direction.

Comment: Read [Giving WordPress Its Own Directory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory). That should help.

Comment: Thanks again. I've successfully moved sites in the past, but was hoping I wouldn't have to in this case, especially since it appears to just be a theme issue. It seems like a theme should be smart enough to deal with a subdirectory install, but oh well!